# Can you Explain step by step how this following code works(Python Program for n-th Fibonacci number)

Tags: python-3.x

I want to know how this program works and give correct output ! I am unable to understand this program.

I din't understant how it give correct output

## Function for nth Fibonacci number

```
def Fibonacci(n): 
if n<0: 
    print("Incorrect input") 
# First Fibonacci number is 0 
elif n==1: 
    return 0
# Second Fibonacci number is 1 
elif n==2: 
    return 1
else: 
    return Fibonacci(n-1)+Fibonacci(n-2) 

# Driver Program 

print(Fibonacci(9)) 

#This code is contributed by Saket Modi
```

Comment: An very good explanation can be found in this Youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qk0zUZW-U_M

Comment: Thank you@neutrino_logic

Answer (score 0):

That's not really what this forum is for. There's a lot of resources online that can help you learn python such as codeacademy, sololearn and learnpython.org plus many YouTube tutorials available. There's nothing complicated about the code you posted. I feel that if you check out one of those resources you might understand the code fairly quickly.